# SQL query Syntax error, Updating a table using data from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have bashing my head against a wall for hours. No doubt this is a simple answer, but I'm either blind or stupid and can't figure it out.

I'm trying to update a column in a table bringing in data from another and matching based on username. Here is my query

```
UPDATE Order5015
SET Order5015.member_id=ow_base_user.id
FROM Order5015, ow_base_user
WHERE Order5015.username = ow_base_user.username
```

When I run this, I get a `1064 syntax error` for the from line.

Can I please get some help from someone much better than me at this!!

Answer (score 0):

Following is correct syntax.

```
UPDATE Order5015
SET Order5015.member_id=ow_base_user.id
FROM Order5015 INNER JOIN ow_base_user
ON Order5015.username = ow_base_user.username
```